# Collapsing factors across multiple columns of a dataframe using the "levels" statement

Tags: r

Quick question about collapsing factors across columns of a dataframe using "levels." Below is the code for a basic dataframe.

```
Service<-c("AS","AS","PS","PS","RS","RS","ES","ES")
 Year<-c("2015","2016","2015","2016","2015","2016","2015","2016")
 Q1<-c("Dissatisfied","Satisfied","Satisfied","Neutral","Dissatisfied","Dissatisfied","Satisfied","Neutral")
Q2<-c("Dissatisfied","Neutral","Satisfied","Dissatisfied","Dissatisfied","Neutral","Satisfied","Satisfied")
Example<-data.frame(Service,Year,Q1,Q2)
```

I can use the following code to easily collapse levels by combining "Satisfied" and "Neutral".

```
levels(Example$Q1)<-c("Dissatisfied","Satisfied","Satisfied")
```

But how would I do this simultaneously across similar columns, say for both column Q1 and Q2? I know there is an easy way using lapply or apply, but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't think your operation was possible. I thought I remembered that collapsing factor levels this way was so severely deprecated that it would throw an error, but since it works for one column, it should (and does) work for multiple columns.

```
 Example[3:4] <- lapply(Example[3:4], 'levels<-', c("Dissatisfied","Satisfied","Satisfied") )
 Example
  Service Year           Q1           Q2
1      AS 2015 Dissatisfied Dissatisfied
2      AS 2016    Satisfied    Satisfied
3      PS 2015    Satisfied    Satisfied
4      PS 2016    Satisfied Dissatisfied
5      RS 2015 Dissatisfied Dissatisfied
6      RS 2016 Dissatisfied    Satisfied
7      ES 2015    Satisfied    Satisfied
8      ES 2016    Satisfied    Satisfied
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Quick question, why does the code require parentheses around 'levels<-'?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply`.  Create a index of columns to be subsetted.  Here, it is the column names that start with "Q" followed by numbers (`^Q\\d+`).  Get the index using `grep`, then use `lapply` on those columns and use `recode` from `library(car)` to change the `levels`.

```
nm1 <- grep("^Q\\d+", names(Example))
Example[nm1] <-  lapply(Example[nm1], recode, 
         'c("Satisified", "Neutral")= "Satisfied"')
```

As we are only changing the "Neutral" to "Satisfied", while the "Satisfied" should remain as such, we can also do

```
Example[nm1] <- lapply(Example[nm1], recode, '"Neutral"= "Satisfied"')
```